# Cannot use "interface" declarations from TypeScript in JS (React Native tests)

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

I have a ReactNative app and I am trying to write a test using Jest. My test need to use classes from a native component (react-native-nfc-manager) and a class I need is declared like this

```
  export interface TagEvent {
    ndefMessage: NdefRecord[];
    maxSize?: number;
    type?: string;
    techTypes?: string[];
    id?: number[];
  }
```

and if I try to use this definition directly like

```
const event = new TagEvent();
```

I get this error

> TypeError: _reactNativeNfcManager.default is not a constructor

I am coming from Java worlds so I think to myself - of course it cannot instantiate an interface, it needs a class so I write a test instance for this interface:

```
class TestTagEvent implements TagEvent {
    ndefMessage: NdefRecord[] = []
    maxSize?: number;
    type?: string;
    techTypes?: string[];
    id?: number[];
}
```

But the problem seem to be different since it does not work either:

> TypeError: _TestTagEvent.TestTagEvent is not a constructor

What am I missing?

Comment: [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAcgJhAZgJQgYwPYCc5QLxQDOwWAlgHYDmA3AFC0XARaICGa0AKq5QKIBuEcsCgBvWlElRyCRAFkIhQjwgAuWLNSYcAbQC6dKVAC2rAB4BlUgC8IAfnXkArsYBGzQ1NCQHREhRoJL3QAC05wRV9iMip9T0lSOF9nN2Y42gBfejQAG1YlKE5FYG4+QWEoUmMwHIhjIWBCQp4BBrEgyRkkBSUVdXgkLWw4fXwofQ6TcytbZJd3LHiob3t1aIClpjQwiMIo-1iDScS51Kx0rNpMcmIoVih1IuJS1oqCcggAd0Lil-LgAAUAEo6FcMDcMLUAHQ5DCUAGsEFAA) is working for me (constructing the class that implements the interface)

Comment: Interfaces can't be instantiated

Comment: I mentioned that I had a second try with class which implements the interface

Answer (score 1):

You can't construct an object using an interface. An interface is just a set of properties that can be used to define required/available properties of variables.

To use the interface to initialize a variable, you want to do this:

```
const eventVar: TagEvent;
```

If you want to use TagEvent as a instantiable object, you need to define it as a class, not an interface. Something like this, where `TagEventProps` is the `TagEvent` interface you defined:

```
class TagEvent {
  constructor(props: TagEventProps) {
    this.ndefMesssage = props.nDefMessage;
    //etc...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After further experiments problem has been solved by adding 'export' to the class. Admittedly, the original error description is absolutely not matching the root cause.

> export class TestTagEvent implements TagEvent {